# How to find the selection position In datetime picker?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Q:**
How to know which position is selected in datetimepicker?
I want to know which section is focused in **datetimepicker**

**[For example: In this how to know that month is selected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRfzs.png)**

Comment: WinForms? WPF? What?

Comment: Yes ,it is WPF but i want to know the concept.For example : if textbox1 is focused then we can write the code as like  `if(textbox1.focused == true)` like this i want to know which section is selected in datetime picker. is their is any solution?

Comment: _"I want to know the concept"_ - I think it's dangerous to assume that any component in any UI framework or any language works in the exact same way as any other UI framework or language's component.

Comment: ok i understood. thanks